# Как сохранить корректировки QSS в Qt Designer?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qss

В *Qt Designer* есть возможность редактирования графического интерфейса при помощи `QSS`, но после изменения частей путем написания кода и закрытии приложения, этот код не сохраняется в окне редактирования его.

Можно ли как-то вывести весь `QSS` и `html` код для последующего сохранения и изменения?

---

**UPD**:

В окне `styleSheet` можно изменять параметры модуля кодом QSS, но после перезахода в `Qt Designer` кода там не будет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример графического интрейфейса:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>320</width>
    <height>240</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>PushButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
      <property name="text">
       <string>PushButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>320</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Правой кнопкой нажав по кнопке вызываю `styleSheet` (показан на изображении) и вставляю следующие:

```
QPushButton{
    min-width:  100px;
    max-width:  100px;
    min-height: 35px;
    max-height: 35px;
}
```

Теперь я применю изменения и кнопка увеличится, но код в `styleSheet` останется только до перезахода, после что бы изменить размер нужно будет заново писать этот код

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос яснее, пожалуйста

Comment: Settings, ваш вопрос не понятен. Приведите код, который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите какие действия надо сделать чтобы получить вашу проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick изменил

Comment: Settings, покажите ваш модуль `.ui`   и покажите (текстом) какие стиль вы хотите добавить, и расскажите как вы делаете добавление стилей...

Comment: @S.Nick добавил пример ui и код css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не понимаю вашей проблемы, сделал как вы написали и все ok.

**q1503842.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic

qtCreatorFile = "q1503842.ui"                # <<<=== Введите файла .ui здесь
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)


class MyApp(QtBaseClass, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1503842.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>320</width>
    <height>240</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>PushButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">QPushButton{
    min-width:  100px;
    max-width:  100px;
    min-height: 35px;
    max-height: 35px;
}</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>PushButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>320</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а теперь перезапустите qt designer и проверьте сохранился ли код css в styleSheet?

Comment: @Settings , да, конечно сохранился. Вы что запускаете в `Qt Designer` мой `q1503842.ui` и видите что-то другое?

Comment: просто у меня после перезапуска qt designer и захода в styleSheet код при помощи которого я изменял кнопку исчезает, но ее размеры остаются

Comment: @Settings , вы не ответили на мой вопрос из предыдущего комментария. Я не понимаю что у вас исчезает. Мой пример у вас работает правильно?

Comment: QPushButton{
    min-width:  100px;
    max-width:  100px;
    min-height: 35px;
    max-height: 35px;
} этот код после перезахода в qt designer исчезнет из styleSheet

Comment: @Settings , я так и не понял, вопрос: "Как сохранить корректировки QSS в Qt Designer?" решен или нет?

Comment: да, вопрос решился путем переустановки qt designer, забыл уже про него, спасибо за помощь)